# Who is the mother of the son of Godzilla from the 1967 movie of the same name?

Tags: plot-device, godzilla

This is the son of Godzilla ([Minya/Minilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minilla)) as seen in the 1967 movie [*Son of Godzilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Godzilla).

[image: Godilla’s son.]

So, Godzilla’s son is “born” after hatching from an egg a trio of giant praying mantises dig up on [Sollgel Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_locations_in_the_Godzilla_films#Sollgel_Island). Godzilla takes on the role of father to this kid, but it’s not clear who the mother of this bundle of joy is or how the egg ended up on the island to begin with.

#### Is there any canonical reference in the Godzilla universe that clearly states who the mother of Minya/Minilla is?

FWIW, the film [*Son of Godzilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Godzilla) was never officially released in theaters in outside of Japan until streaming services started to carry the original Japanese film with translated subtitles.

Comment: I want to say "Godzilla herself", but that would immediately raise another question.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a dupe... Sure, Godzilla's gender is ambiguous, but being male or female doesn't solve the problem of who's the other parent?

Comment: By the way, the off-topic comment has been itching me for two days, and someone has to say it: *man, this is one **ugly** baby!*

Comment: Some amphibians are capable of [parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis), as are [some snakes](https://www.livescience.com/52286-water-snake-virgin-birth.html) and [Kamodo Dragons](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-komodo-d/). Maybe Godzilla is a lady and she don't need no damn man :)

Comment: @Jenayah There are some babies that only a mother could love .. which explains the absence of Minya's mother :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### There are several, conflicting, stories about Minilla’s background; and, I don't think there is a *definitive* consensus on where he actually came from.

Some stories contradict one another, or are at least ambiguous. Others were created as the franchise developed and expanded. That, and there's much apocrypha, too!

Even his name is somewhat problematic.

- **Minilla**: That is the anglicized version used for the U.S. release and Minira is the Japanese version ('mini' and 'Gojira'). Mina and Milla are also used in dubbed versions of the film. In scripts running up to the filming, but prior to the naming contest created by Toho for the film, he was called *Kodomo Gojira* (child godzilla) or *Gojira Junia* (godzilla junior). In the shooting script he's named *Kojira* (childzilla).
- **Godzilla Junior**: As referred to in [*Godzilla vs. Destoroyah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Destoroyah) (1995). Although Minilla's name sometimes is also the name of a different *Kojira* in the Heisei series.

This is not at all comprehensive, BTW. On top of this, there are variations of his name due to multiple versions across different media, over a long timeline, including language changes based upon translations (by many people) of dubbing and sub-titles!?!

Including a time when he shows up for no apparent reason: [*Godzilla: Final Wars* (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_Final_Wars).

What is generally accepted is that he—and it is a 'he' (Ryffe, 1998, p. 141)—is a [godzillasaurus](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Godzillasaurus). Minilla as seen in [*Son of Godzilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Godzilla) (1967), as noted in the question above, was born prematurely due to the Kamacuras attack.

In *Son of Godzilla* he is *adopted* and trained by Godzilla. However, there is no indication that he is related directly (biologically) to Godzilla… ***only*** that he is adopted.

In, for example, [*Go! Greenman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ike!_Greenman) (1973 TV series), he is a blood-thirsty creation of Tonchiki, a servant of Maoh.

As the franchise developed and expanded across media (film, TV, etc.) two versions appear: the goofy version we know and love/hate and a darker version as seen in the *Go! Greenman*  TV series.

In the end, director Jun Fukuda said Minilla was simply created to increase production value and draw a broader, more diverse, audience.

In this way, then, although there is a somewhat coherent idea for Minilla, there is no clear or definitive origin story.

Minilla's origin story is, quite literally, apocrypha.

---

Resources (the first three are—IMO—the most informative):

1. *Japan's Favorite Mon-Star: The Unauthorized Biography of "The Big G"*, Steve Ryffe (1998)
2. "The Complete Godzilla Chronology 1954-2004" by August Ragone and Bob Eggleton (2014; Famous Monsters of Filmland. No. 274.).
3. "Twenty-five Years with Godzilla" by Ed Godziszewski (1979; Fangoria. No. 1)
4. *All Toho Monsters Pictorial Book*, published by Yosensha (2014)
5. *Toho Special Effects Movie Complete Works*, published by Village Books (2012)
6. *Encyclopedia of Godzilla (Mechagodzilla Edition)*, published by Gakken (1993)
7. *The Toho Studios Story: A History and Complete Filmography*, by Stuart Galbraith (2008)
8. *The Official Godzilla Compendium*, J.D. Lees and Marc Cerasini (1998)